# Easy SQL Logic question: having count (*) = 2

Tags: mysql, sql

I know this is an easy question, but I am not sure whats the logic behind placing =2 after count (*):

```
select customer_id, name
from(
select 
    c.customer_id,
    c.name 
    , month(order_date) as m
from
customers c 
inner join orders o on (c.customer_id = o.customer_id)
inner join  product p on (p.product_id = o.product_id)
where order_date between "2020-06-01" and "2020-07-31"
group by 
customer_id, name, month(order_date)
having sum(p.price * o.quantity) >= 100
    ) random group by customer_id, name 
    having count(1) =2
```

having count(1) =2 can be count(*) = 2. My question is, what does implementing =2 do in this logic? Sorry for the noob question!

For more context:
I would like to get customer_id and customer_name of customers who have spent at least $100 in each month of June and July 2020. Then I will return the results in any order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is returning customers who spent more than 100 in exactly two months -- so that would be both June and July.

The subquery is returning customer/month combinations that meet the threshold of spending for those two months.

Comment: Sorry, so to confirm, =2 is saying that you would like to get the 2 months (July and June), correct? Since if I execute =1 it returns the wrong person, and if I execute =3, it doesnt return anything. I know this is dependent on the table. 

But = 2 represents the two months?

Comment: @BruceReyes . . . It represents the two months, specifically because the inner `where` is limiting the results to only those two months.

Comment: Great! Thank you, Gordon! Appreciate the help